# How did Luke's X-wing fly from Ahch-To?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, the-rise-of-skywalker

How did Luke's X-wing fly from Ahch-To? I thought it was damaged beyond repair.

Comment: A wizard did it.

Answer (score 10):

While it's true that Luke's X-Wing is in bad shape (missing [part of a wing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGBWn.png) as well as several other key components), it's worth pointing out that a lot of the major bits that are needed to get it into space, such as repulsorlifts, and the bits that are needed to get it into hyperspace, such as hyperdrive motivators, are housed inside the *main body* of the ship rather than on the wings. Rey doesn't need to fly it as a combat fighter, she just needs it to limp into orbit and not kill her when she lands at her destination.

[image]

Apparently the film's [official novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_Expanded_Edition) concurs with my guess

> It was old tech, and it had taken some fast thinking and even faster fingers to get it flight worthy - the wing patched with the door to Luke’s hut, shield panels scavenged from the TIE wreckage, and a hefty amount of rewiring.
>
> ...
>
> It might never fight again - not without help from Rose and her parts-requisition channels.

---

It's also worthy of mention that we've seen that exact T-65b X-Wing submerged before and **it worked just fine almost straight away afterwards**. If anything, seawater would probably less damaging for a piece of fine electronics than swamp ooze.

Comment: "seawater would probably less damaging for a piece of fine electronics" No: saltwater is, more or less, instant metal corrosion. (You may have noticed the high investments in corrosion-resistant paint given to saltwater vessel hulls and salt water bridges. There's a reason for that.)

Comment: @Lexible that and those items normally have anodes installed that are made of different metals that are designed to reduce corrosion and need to be replaced at regular intervals.

Comment: Built Incom-tough. :)

Comment: @MissouriSpartan - *"And that's why I always buy Incom. When you need reliability **and** affordability"* [turns both heads toward camera and smile]

Comment: @MissouriSpartan the amount of punishment the Millennium Falcon takes in the new trilogy really stretches the suspension of disbelief - they literally drive it into rock many many times and fly away without issue.  Rey flying Luke’s X-Wing is nothing compared to that.

Comment: Maybe the xwing is a Jedi.  Fyi, salt water is one of the most corrosive substances ... It might not be quick but not alot can stop it indefinitely.